# Including column flag only if specific row exist in other table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Flag value true only if the row exist otherwise make it false.

I solved the solution in SQL but I'm having a problem with entity framework.
Here is the SQL query:

```sql
select p.ProductID,  
       (case when c.UserID = 3 then 'true' else 'false' end) as flag
    from product as p  
    left join SavedItem as c 
    on p.ProductID = c.ProductID
```

This query runs accurately, it shows all records and only makes flag true if the column exists in a `SavedItem` table.
How can I do that in entity framework?

Answer (score 1):

this might be a problem of left join in Entity framework. Try this code:

```
var result = from p in Product
    join c in SavedItem on p.ProductID equals c.ProductID into lj
    from c in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {
    p.ProductID,
    flag = (c.UserID == 3 ? 'true' : 'false')
};
```

Comment: That's great but the problem is when 2 or more user save the same product than it returns duplicate products.

Comment: I solved this problem in SQL. here the sql query:  [left join SavedItem as c  on product.ProductID = c.ProductID and c.UserID = 3]

Comment: I added [and c.userID = 3] next to left join how can I do that in entity framework?